# pass an argument type object in an iterate function (each) with handlears

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, handlebars.js, each

I want to pass an object as an argument in  a function which exists in an each function using handlebars, but the object passed is undefines in the loop function while everything is alright outside the "each"

```
{{#each sits}}
<tr>
      <td class="content content-center">{{@key}}</td>
      <td class="content ar">{{getMaxFormula terms sits 'd' sits.name}}</td>
</tr>
{{\each}}
```

in my json file :

```
{
"terms": [
  {
     "evt": "d",
     "cap": 50000,
     "type": "d"
  }
  ],
"sits": {
  "2015": {
     "d": 50000,
     "i": 0,
     "a": 0,
     "cumul": 3491.637,
     "premium": 5000,
     "com": -1500,
     "term": -77.151,
     "taxEco": 1500
  },
  "2016": {
     "d": 46508.363,
     "i": 0,
     "a": 0,
     "cumul": 9131.576,
     "premium": 6000,
     "com": -550,
     "term": -89.622,
     "taxEco": 1800
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{{#each sits as |value key|}}
    <tr>
      <td class="content content-center">{{key}}</td>
    </tr>
{{/each}}
```

But what is sits.name here:

```
<td class="content ar">{{getMaxFormula terms sits 'd' sits.name}}</td>
```

Comment: sorry, my mistake, it is sits.term, and in the getMaxFormula function the problem, the display of the key is alrigth